# How to apply css customization in a PHP snippet plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, code-snippets

I'm using the xyz Snippet PHP plugin to integrate an API into a wordpress theme. There is an HTML with the proper class IDs. How do I assign a custom css to this html? Can I point to an external .css file, right? If yes, what folder should I put this file to work on the snippet?

Comment: Well since the output of the php plugin should be part of a single HTML DOM, you can pretty much add css file to the header of the theme with your css style... No reason to solve it other way (unless it generates iframed content)

Comment: Php is placed in the dashboard of the plugin, and it gives me a snippet to per in the theme page, so it would be unfeasible to use this css method of the theme because it is not loaded along with the theme. The php makes an API call and only then the html is loaded.

I wanted to use external file to make it easier to edit, but not to waste time on how to do this, I decided to edit the css directly in the html divs, since there will not be many changes.

But thanks for the answer.